# C++ float rounding (error?)

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision, floating-point-conversion

Why when I use multiplication

```
float a= 1.0500000f;
float b= a*100.0f;
```

why b is 104.99999 but not 105.0 ?

and when I

```
int f= (int)b;
```

f is 104

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for everything you need to know. As for the senond part, it's due to truncation.

Comment: there are lots of questions about this "problem" on this site. Read more http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers are not infinitely accurate -- [the wikipedia page on Float numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) is quite interesting to read.

On your second question: `(int)b` truncates anything that occurs after the comma. This means that, in your case, `104.99999` becomes `104`. So when you create a rounding error, and then cast it to an integer, you are indeed running the risk of getting a lower number.

Comment: Somewhat wrong on the second part, casting to `int` doesn't *round* down, it simply *truncates* the value.

Comment: ... the result of which is that the number is rounded down. But yes, I have updated my post.

Comment: It is not rounded down if it is negative.